# Postgresql full text (pg_trgm) to handle exact matches better?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

So i have a simple scenario. I have a table of venues (event venues, etc). And my query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM venues WHERE venues.name % 'Philips Arena' ORDER BY similarity(venues.name, 'Philips Arena') DESC
```

This technically works, I get Philips Arena as the first result, but I also get a ton of other results that shouldn't be suggested. Like 'TGE Arena' and 'LG Arena'. I'd prefer that they get excluded. Also, if I search for just 'Arena' I'd still like suggestions. But if there is an obvious outlier in the result, like Philips Arena in the above example, I'd like to only return that.

Any ideas how I can do this? I'm hoping pg_trgm has a setting for something like this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: any update on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll help you. Word with "A" would be more important than others.

```
SELECT title, ts_rank_cd(fts,q)
FROM titles, to_tsquery('something:B|somebody:B|important:A') q
WHERE fts @@ q ORDER BY ts_rank_cd DESC, Length(title) LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This answer uses full-text search while the OP asked about pg_trgm extension - these are completely different concepts